# Allowing a program through a Windows Firewall

Tags: windows

I am new to Windows Firewall. I have seen this dialog and unable to understand its meaning.

[image]

The above dialog says that **"Allow python to communicate on these networks:"**. It then gives two checkboxes, one for each Private network and one for Public network.

So, my questions are:

1. What is the difference between a private network and a public network? Which network out of these, does internet belong to?
2. What is the meaning of allowing a program to communicate on a given network?

   Let's take it from both Client as well as Server perspective:

   - A program (acting as client), when allowed through firewall on a given network (public/private) - does it mean that it can establish socket connection with other computers within the same network?
   - A program (acting as server), when allowed through firewall - does it mean that it can accept socket connections from other computers within the same network?
3. How can I control a program to either listen for connections OR to establish connections?

   By that I mean, How can I control that any python program (`python.exe`) must not be allowed to listen for connections?

Comment: A bit of explanation for q.1 here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/choosing-network-location#1TC=windows-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The difference between the two is the level of trust Windows give it. Both are [LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network)s. For example, you could consider a Windows "private network" as your home network and a public one as a wifi hotspot in a café. Windows does not behave the same on public or private network (see [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/choosing-network-location#1TC=windows-7)).
   Internet doesn't "belong" to a LAN; a LAN can be connected to the Internet.
2. Allowing a program to communicate on a given network on Windows means enabling firewall rules to let him connect to another machine or listen for connections of other machines through that network. It does mean it can establish connections through sockets, yes, but not only from or to machines from the same network if the LAN is connected to other networks (such as Internet). However, outgoing or incoming trafic are usually different firewall rules so you should check which ones you want to enable/disable.
3. As stated above, you can configure you firewall for connections in one way or the other. Also, listening on a port can require privileges so you should check which ones are necessary in order to block programs.

Comment: Whenever I connect my laptop to my internal network for internet access, it  asks me whether I want to set my internal network as private or public network. So, it contradicts with your statement "Internet doesn't belong to LAN"

Comment: Moreover, can you also clarify "It does mean it can establish connections through sockets, yes, but not only from or to machines from the same network if the LAN is connected to other networks (such as Internet)." with some good eg. in the answer.

Comment: You can configure networks as Private or Public (or Business/Corporate) in Windows. Windows will then have multiple different settings (Homegroup, firewall etc.) it applies depending on that trust level.  Maybe this analogy will help: you're fine walking around naked at home ('private network') but might want to put on some clothes before you go to the coffee shop. (public network. anyone can see/interact with your private bits).

Answer (score 1):

## 1. Private and public network

They are meant mainly to be used by roaming machines. Whenever you connect to a new network, windows will ask you to identify the type of network you are one (private/business/public). It allows the firewall to be configure with different set of rules depending on where you are connecting your machine on.

The current type of network should be indicated in the network control panel and also in the Firewall console add-in (see 3.)

## 2. Connections

Normally, the "accept connection from" and "establish connection to" network should be separated. I think to recall they are in windows policies and the OS will ask you both if it needs both permissions. They are known as the "inbound rules" and "outbound rules".

## 3. Advanced rules/check

You can find the rules in the firewall console add-in `wf.msc`.

Comment: How can I get to know about windows policies for it ? Moreover, here the dialog does not specify, whether python is accepting inbound connection or it's making outbound connection ?

Answer (score 1):

First, about the Firewall. It's just a gate and by default its close. No connection gets in or out. You can manually configure it to allow certain ports to be opened. Some programs will open the ports they need and will prompt you similar to your post.

PRIVATE & PUBLIC networks are your "default" Firewall profiles. You typically select Private or Public every time you connect to a new network, like when you connect to a new WiFi.

Whatever profile you choose for Python will determine its usability. If you allow it to connect only in your Private network, then when you work on Public networks, Python will not be able to establish connections.

> Will it establish client/server connections?

**Yes** (if its programmed to do so). **The selection of Private or Public profile does not affect the fact that Python is opening ports for itself. It will open ports for your connection.** It's just that if you select Private, these connections would only be open if your in your Private network and close if your in a Public network. On the other hand, if you select Public, Python will make these connections regardless of what network connection you are using.

You can control Python from the Firewall settings.